# List field index in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, listfield

I m going through ListField,..I m getting problem when i click on the selected index....

I want the code,when i click on the selected index,it is showing all the profiles for the particular index

```
  public class ListEmployees extends MainScreen implements ListFieldCallback
    {
             ListField list;
        String[]  items= {"Srikanth","Pradeep","Ranjith"}; 
        public ListEmployees()
        {
            setTitle("List Screen");
            list = new ListField();
            list.setSize(3);
            list.setCallback(this);

            add(list);
        }
```

> using switch case

```
public void drawListRow(ListField listField, Graphics g, int index,int y, int width) 
{
    int a= listField.getSelectedIndex();
    g.drawText(items[a], 0, y,0,50);

    switch(a)
    {
    case 0 :
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        Bitmap srikanthImg = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("srikanth.jpg");
        if(list.getSelectedIndex()==0)
            showMessage(srikanthImg,"Srikanth","1363");
        else 
            break;
        //Dialog.alert("The selected element is: " + Integer .toString ());
        break;
    case 1 :
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    Bitmap PradeepImg = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("pradeep.jpg");
    showMessage(PradeepImg,"Pradeep","1303");
    break;
case 2 :
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    Bitmap ranjithImg = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("ranjith.jpg");
    showMessage(ranjithImg,"ranjith","1333");
    break;

default :
        Dialog.alert("No Information Found !!!");
    }
}
private void showMessage(Bitmap map, String name1, String empId1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String data = name1 + "\n"+empId1;
    UiEngine ui = Ui.getUiEngine();
    Screen screen = new Dialog(Dialog.D_OK, data, Dialog.OK, map, FIELD_HCENTER);
    ui.queueStatus(screen, 1, true);
```

Comment: can you explain your question it is not clear what you want to do ???

Answer (score 0):

`ListFieldCallback.drawListRow()` is just for drawing a list item representation on UI.

Looks like you are looking for how to catch on-list click event. If yes, then override `ListField.navigationClick()`.